# Current flow in wire due to TEM wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Below I've drawn (skillfully) a wire and AC voltage applied at one end. Note the wire goes on indefinitely.

[image: Wire with AC source at one end.]

I am confused on the direction at which the E field propagates and the direction at which it is polarized. Would the E field be travelling in the X direction and polarized in the Y direction? but then the current wouldn't be flowing in the X direction?

Comment: if you assume ideal conductivity there is no electric field in the wire, so where is your confusion?

Comment: Assume non-ideal conductivity  < infinity, I am trying to picture the direction at which the field is propagating and the direction the electric field is polarized, which would result in a current in the wire.

Comment: if the conductivity is finite then there is a small longitudinal component of the E field along the wire and the field is not purely TEM. At any rate, the current is along the wire although the energy is propagated by the Poynting vector field $S=E x H$ *between* the wires and not in the wires.

Comment: so, the electric field would be travelling in the +y direction and polarized in the XZ plane? Though this is contrary to what WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance is saying.

Comment: in the (xy) plane (between the wires)  the E field is polarized along the y axis ($E_y$), while the H field is along the (z) axis ($H_z$), their cross product S is along the (x) axis($S_x$, no current is flowing along (y), only along (x) $J_x \approx \frac {dH_z}{dy}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, in a TEM wave both the electric and magnetic fields are confined to the plane normal to the wire (the $yz$ plane in your notation).

In a true TEM wave, the conductors must be *perfect* ($\sigma\to\infty$), so that, even though the charges are shuttling back and forth along the wire, no field is needed.

This is a rather peculiar limiting case. To understand what is going on physically, one needs to analyse the problem assuming a finite conductivity. In this case, you find that the electric field indeed has a nonzero $x$ component, shuttling the charges back and forth. As you raise the conductivity in this analysis, this component of the field vanishes.

Comment: Okay, so the TEM is propagating in the positive x direction, and the E & M fields are confined in the YZ plane. What is making the charges have a net displacement in +x axis direction?

Comment: @Lone.L The fact that infinite, instantaneous conductivity means, amongst other things, that the charges have zero inertial mass and therefore take no force to move. As I said, you need to look at a finite conductivity case, with an $x$ component of the electric field for insight. As $\sigma\to\infty$ the $x$ component tends to nought.